# Powershell - Join-Object with NO matching property value

Tags: powershell

I have a script that is working at getting different pieces of computer data and then exporting to a csv. Current issue that I am having is that the script works completely flawless on one machine, but can no longer get any other machine to behave the same without some errors even though using the same module which is JoinModule.

So, I am getting 3 pieces of data that is currently in 2 objects, $ip and $compdock.

$ip contains the IP address of the computer. (header = "IPV4Address")
$compdock contains both the computer name and the docking station serial number. (headers = "PSComptuerName, serialnumber")

I need to export this data to a csv and keep everything on the same line and then append so I can add more data the next loop.

The working function from the 1st machine is

```
$data = Join-Object -Left $ip -Right $compdock
$data | Export-Csv -Path $Path -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

Expected Output CSV File

| IPV4Address | PSComputerName | serialnumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 192.168.1.12 | computer1 | 1122334 |
| 192.168.1.14 | computer2 | 2255448 |

This no longer works on any new machine where we install the module as it is wanting the LeftJoin and RightJoin properties. I have not been able to determine how to join the 2 without a matching property value and without losing any data from both objects. Also confused in general why it is working on one machine and no others.

All help is appreciated.

**UPDATED**

The other machines are asking for an input for the LeftJoinProperties and RightJoinProperties, but due to the fact that they don't have a matching property I don't know how to do the join. Since this is the case, I do not have any output for the other machines.

The computer data is being pulled through live machines.

```
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $OUPath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

Foreach ($Computer in $Computers){
    $ip = Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select IPV4Address
    $compdock = gwmi -n root\dell\sysinv dell_softwareidentity -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.ElementName -like "WD19*"} | select pscomputername, serialnumber
    if ($ip -eq $null){
        $ip = '' | Select IPV4Address
        $ip.IPV4Address = "Computer Not On"
        $compdock = '' | Select PSComputerName, serialnumber
        $compdock.PSComputerName = $Computer
        $compdock.serialnumber = ""
    } elseif ($compdock -eq $null){
        $compdock = '' | Select PSComputerName, serialnumber
        $compdock.PSComputerName = $Computer
        $compdock.serialnumber = "No Dock Found"
    }
    $data = Join-Object -Left $ip -Right $compdock
    $data | Export-Csv -Path $Path -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Our environment is working with Dell computers and docking stations.

Comment: What do you get instead? Are there any errors? Please, add the source data (e g. `$ip | ConvertTo-Csv` and `$compdock ConvertTo-Csv`) to the question.

Comment: I have added and UPDATED section that may answer a bit more for you.

Comment: but you have a matching property, you just discard it before you can use it. change your `Test-Connection` line's `Select-Object` to `|Select-Object Address,IPV4Address` and join on `$IP.Address` = `$compdock.PSComputerName`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to go back to the basics:

```
Install-Module -Name JoinModule -Force
```

Do you have the same version of the module installed

```
Get-Command Join-Object

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Join-Object                                        3.8.3      JoinModule
```

Does it work predefined data?

```
$ip = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
IPV4Address
192.168.1.12
192.168.1.14
'@

$compdock = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
PSComputerName,serialnumber
computer1,1122334
computer2,2255448
'@

Join-Object -Left $ip -Right $compdock
```

Expected results:

```
IPV4Address  PSComputerName serialnumber
-----------  -------------- ------------
192.168.1.12 computer1      1122334
192.168.1.14 computer2      2255448
```

If this still works, it is unlikely a `Join-Object` issue.
What else could be going wrong?

- `$ip` or `$compdock` do not contain (any) or unexpected data
  check: `$ip | ConvertTo-Csv` and `$compdock ConvertTo-Csv`
- check whether `$Computers` is filled
  use e.g.: `Write-Host $Computers`
- check the response of:
  `Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $OUPath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`

Comment: The module has been removed and reinstalled numerous times in testing with still the same results. Even with the code you have provided above I still run into the issue with the properties. So, once executed I am left on the command line with "LeftJoinProperty[0]:" waiting for user input.

I am getting my computer list by pulling live data from ActiveDirectory based off of a certain OU.

Comment: I don't think it is due to the `JoinModule` but due to the data you feed it with (which is probably empty). Again: **Does it work predefined data?** as explained above?

Comment: As I had stated in my comment above, it still is not working even using the example you had above with the manual data.

Comment: @Link The behavior you describe matches that of the [`Join-Object` module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join-Object/2.0.1/Content/Join-Object.ps1) - **not** `JoinModule`. Are you 100% sure you didn't accidentally `Install-Module Join-Object` instead of `Install-Module JoinModule`? What does `Get-Command Join-Object -All` show?

Comment: I show "Name | Join-Object", "Version | 3.8.3", "Source | JoinModule". I also have verified in the file location "C:\Windows\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules" that I have the JoinModule folder.

Comment: And that result is consistent across the computer that works fine with the command and one that does not.

Comment: Does anything come out from `Join-Object` using different parameters or data? What does `Join-Object ?` return? Expected:
NAME
    Join-Object

SYNOPSIS
    Combines two object lists based on a related property between them.
...